# T-SQL / Find all dots in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like that :

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    CODE nvarchar(max)
);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('320.01.001'),('320.01.002'),('320.001.002'),('320.01.002.0003.0002')
SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

Result:

[image]

I want to count of dots in a column .

My excepted result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty simple method is:

```
select t.*, s.num_dots
from @table t cross apply
     (select count(*) - 1 as num_dots
      from string_split(t.code, '.') s
     ) s;
```

A more traditional method uses the difference between the lengths of two strings:

```
select t.*,
       len(t.code) - len(replace(t.code, '.', '')) as num_dots
from @table t;
```

I actually do not have a sense of which of these is faster.  If I had to guess, I would guess the second, but if performance is an issue, you should test the two versions.